# Token refresh concurrency issue in Dart with ASP.NET Core WebAPI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, dart, flutter, jwt

I wrote a simple application in Flutter using Dart. I use JWT tokens to authenticate user. Primary token is valid only 60 seconds.
When user send a request with expired token the webapi returns 401.
Then in my Dart code I check if statuscode of response is 401
If yes, then I send a request to RefreshToken endpoint and send request one more time (this request which returned 401 earlier).

If user does many actions too fast, expired token is renewed many times.
I'd like to avoid this.
In perfect soultion when token is being refreshing, other requests should wait.

Answer (score 2):

I faced similar problem and tried to solve it using below approach.

I use `flutter-redux` to manage the state on client side.

1. Get jwt token after login
2. Decode the jwt token on client side as responded from server.
3. It contains a timeout - time of expiration.
4. Create a redux middleware on client side lets say `_createRefreshTokenMiddleware`.
5. Every request from client should go through this middle-ware before sending to server.
6. In this middle-ware, with every requests to server, check the token timeout, if token is expired, hold those request, send request to server to refresh token, wait until received new token, use this new token to send those request to server.
7. All other requests for which token will expire will wait on a common promise, lets say `refreshTokenPromise` to get refreshToken get resolved first. In this way you don't have to send multiple refreshToken requests.
8. If the token is still valid, let the requests to go through.

Refer below example -

**Your middleware :**

```
Middleware<AppState> _createRefreshTokenMiddleware() {
  return (Store store, action, NextDispatcher next) async {
    AppState appState = store.state;
    AuthState auth =  appState.auth;

    if (isTokenExpired(auth)) {
      if (auth.refreshTokenPromise == null) {
        refreshToken(store).then((res) => next(action));
      } else {
        auth.refreshTokenPromise.then((res) => next(action));
      }
    }
    next(action);
  };
}
```

All the requests for which token is expired will wait on `refreshTokenPromise` to get resolved and as soon as that is resolved all of the pending requests will have new updated token set in request header (e.g).

**Checking for token expiration :**

```
bool isTokenExpired(AuthState auth) {
  int bufferSeconds = 10;
  if(auth != null && auth.authTokens != null && auth.authTokens.tokenExpiryTime != null) {
    var currentTime = DateTime.now();
    Duration durationRemaining = auth.authTokens.tokenExpiryTime.difference(currentTime);

    return (durationRemaining.inSeconds - bufferSeconds) <= 0 ? true : false;

  }
  return false;
}
```

You send the request to refresh token 10 seconds before it is actually expired.

**AuthState Model:**

@immutable
class AuthState {

```
// properties
final bool isAuthenticated;
final bool isAuthenticating;
final AuthTokens authTokens;
final String error;
final Future<dynamic> refreshTokenPromise;

// constructor with default
AuthState({
    this.isAuthenticated = false,
    this.isAuthenticating = false,
    this.authTokens,
    this.error,
    this.refreshTokenPromise,
});
```

}

Your auth-state model can be like above.

**AuthToken:**

```
@immutable
class AuthTokens {

  // properties
  final String accessToken;
  final String refreshToken;
  final DateTime tokenExpiryTime;

  // constructor with default
  AuthTokens({
    this.accessToken,
    this.refreshToken,
    this.tokenExpiryTime,
  });
 }
```

Although I have given redux based solution here but same strategy can be applied anywhere else as well. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

As you correctly pointed out, the problem is that the authorization server receives too many token refresh request. Each particular user should only send one refresh request and rely on the results of that request.

Flutter's async package has a handy class called [AsyncMemoizer](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/package-async_async/AsyncMemoizer-class.html) for cases like this.
From the API reference:

> A class for running an asynchronous function exactly once and caching its result.
>
> An AsyncMemoizer is used when some function may be run multiple times
> in order to get its result, but it only actually needs to be run once
> for its effect. To memoize the result of an async function, you can
> create a memoizer outside the function (for example as an instance
> field if you want to memoize the result of a method), and then wrap
> the function's body in a call to runOnce.

Assuming that the component of your app that handles all token requests is a singleton, you can cache the tokenrequests like that:

```
class TokenDataSource {
  AsyncMemoizer<TokenResponse> tokenRequestMemoizer = AsyncMemoizer();
  ...

  @override
  Future<Tokens> verifyAndRefreshTokens() async {

    var tokenResponse = await tokenRequestMemoizer.runOnce(() {
      // run your token request code 
    });
    // once the request is done, reset the memoizer so that future clients don't receive the cached tokens
    tokenRequestMemoizer = AsyncMemoizer(); 

    // return results
  }
}
```

This will make all clients of TokenDataSource wait for the same token request instead of launching a new one.